# Why Does This While Loop With A Condition Hang?

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

Important Updates: Code line 12 changed from "universalTracker + 2" to "universalTracker += 2"

I'm doing the adjacentElementsProduct challenge on CodeSignal, and it's asking me to create a function that shows the highest product from each adjacent pair of numbers in the list. I wrote this, and I can't seem to find what's wrong with it. Once I press run in VSCode, it just hangs. I have to force quit the program.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    highestProduct = 0
    universalTracker = 0
    firstNum = inputArray[universalTracker]
    secondNum = inputArray[universalTracker + 1]
    arrayLength = len(inputArray)

    while universalTracker != (arrayLength - 1):
        currentProduct = firstNum * secondNum
        if currentProduct > highestProduct:
            highestProduct = currentProduct
        universalTracker += 2

adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3])
```

If anyone could give me an explanation as to what I did wrong, a working solution, and why it works, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple
Just change **while** **loop** condition to

```
while universalTracker >= (arrayLength - 1):
```

Because, let's say your array length is 5, and universalTracker is updating by 2, it won't be equal to 5
It will be 2,4,6,8,10,12 ... and so on.

Let me know if this makes sense..

Comment: This does make sense, however the output is 0. I want to say because the loop just ends, since universalTracker starts out as 0, and since it's not higher than (arrayLength - 1), it just ends. I tried using !>=, but that's too much for python to handle! I also tried using <= and that worked, however the output is 18, when it should be 21 since in the array, [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], 7 * 3 is the greatest and equals 21.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, you are doing the following inside the while loop.

```
universalTracker + 2
```

This isn't really updating the variable that you intended to update.

To make it work, you should do

```
universalTracker = universalTracker+2
```

Or equivalently

```
universalTracker += 2
```

Comment: I changed it, and if I use "universalTracker += 1", it completes successfully but with the wrong value, or if I use "universalTracker += 2", it hangs.

Comment: As mentioned by @Aryan in the subsequent answer, you can change the while condition too. This is happening because you are using a NOT EQUAL TO condition. With +1 change, you land to a particular case where the value is indeed equal, hence the loop stops. With +2 you're just skipping the particular case where it should be equal.